# Constructing A linear system with unknown variables

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am a little confused on the following problems and would love some clarification. Can someone confirm for me if my approach is correct?

Approach: 
turn this variables into row echelon form and get rid of any redundant equations that turn to 0. After I do this, I end up with 3 equations that equal something (this will be my linear system), 2 equations that became zero (which I ignore) and done.

Confusion: 
A friend earlier today mentioned me that I most before doing echelon form pass the numbers to the left and move the $x_i$ to the right and then solve. I don't see how this is correct or useful.

Am I correct? Did I miss something?

thank you for any comments and your help.

> Construct a linear system with five unknowns that its set of all
>   possible solutions strictly contains the plane $$ \begin{cases} x_1 =
> > -1 + s - t \\ x_2 = 2 + 2s + 2t \\ x_3 = -s \\ x_4 = -2 + 2t \\ x_5 = -1 + 3s + t \end{cases} $$

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, you are referring to problem 6? Also I believe the preferred format here is to transcribe any image sources for the question, rather than just posting an image (it's not very amenable to screen readers for example).

Comment: Yes, problem #6. Sorry regarding posting an image rather than transcribing its sources. I was not aware.

Comment: Please demonstrate what you mean by “turn this [sic] variables into row echelon form.”